# How do I write and delete Objects from a RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, file, object, methods, randomaccessfile

I am currently working on a school project for which I need to save my data to a `RandomAccessFile`. I figured that this is by far not the most efficient way, but I have to do it. Note: I have to use the RandomAccessFile class.

I understand how I can save simple `strings` and `int` created in the main method to a file, but I am having trouble transferring this knowledge onto my own program.

I have 4 different classes, i.e. `Database`, `Group`, `Student`, `Rehearsal`. The `Database` class lets you add groups to a linked list of groups. To each group, you can then add students (see below) as well as rehearsal dates (its a theatre management program). These are added to `linkedlist<Student>` and `linkedlist<Rehearsal>` respectively.

This is my `addStudent` method in the `Group` class that adds a student to the linkedlist of a  group that was created.

```
public void addStudent(int id, String firstname, String lastname) throws IOException {
    Student newstudent = new Student(id, firstname, lastname);
    if (!Students.contains(newstudent)) {
        Students.add(newstudent);
} else 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student with ID " + id
                + " already exists in group!", "Error",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

How do I let the method automatically write the student object to the file when it is executed?

This is my `removeStudent` method:

```
public void removeStudent(int id) {
    if (!Students.remove(new Student(id, null, null))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student with ID[" + id
                + "] not present. System unchanged.");

    } 
}
```

Pretty much the same question, how can I then delete a specific object from the file when the method is executed. If you could me help me out on that as well, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

override the `toString()` method of object class in the way you want to write to the file!

then loop using `foreach` over the `linkedlist` and call `toString()` on student object and write to file

example:

```
fileOutputStream outStream=newFileOutputStream("../RandomAccessFile");//path where you want to create file
foreach(Student s in linkedlist)
{
  outStream.println(s.toString()+"/n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a RandomAccessFile, is it? Because I need to save my data using the RandomAccessFile class and I need to use the seek method when writing, deleting or reading from file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete anything from a `RandomAccessFile` except by implementing some file protocol that your code understands, for example filling a record with nulls, assuming your file has records, and assuming that all-nulls (or whatever) is not a legal record value. Or implement a byte header on each record such that 1 means present and 0 means deleted, or *vice versa.*